# Forcing RVO / move construction when returning by value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, return-value-optimization

Say I have an object 'foo' with a copy constructor and a move constructor, and a function

```
foo f() {
    foo bar;
    /* do some work */
    return bar;
}
```

The standard appears to state that the compiler will try to do: NRVO, return by r-value ref, return by value, fail; in that order.

Is there any way to force the compiler to never return by value, since my copy constructor is quite expensive?

Comment: Have you profiled and determined that there is an actual bottleneck?

Comment: The standard defines NRVO? News to me...

Comment: (I acknowledge that it allows NRVO)

Comment: It 'allows' NRVO, and 'allows' the return to be by rvalue reference, but doesn't seem to require either, apart from priority if they do happen. Esentially I want to require either to happen, but never the copy-constructor in some arbitrary function foo f();

Comment: `f()` always returns by value and never returns an rvalue ref. NRVO means `bar` is constructed in the proper place for a return value. If bar is movable then if NRVO cannot be done the return value is move constructed from bar. This seems to be what you mean by 'return by r-value ref' but that's not an accurate description. If it cannot be moved then it is copy constructed. This seems to be what you mean by 'return by value' but that's also not accurate. Again `f()` always returns by value and the internal details of how the return value is constructed do not change that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> the compiler will try to do: NRVO, return by r-value ref, return by value, fail; in that order.

The wording above is imprecise and might indicate a misunderstanding on your side. The compiler *can* use NRVO (most will), if that is not available it will *always* return by value, the difference is how the returned value will be constructed. If your type has a move constructor, the compiler **must** use that constructor and will only fall to use a copy constructor if your type does not have a move constructor.

That is, if your type has a move constructor a compiler that used the copy constructor would not be C++11 compliant.

Comment: From my testing with g++ and clang, it looks like it uses the copy-constructor when NRVO doesn't work. See http://ideone.com/zoeixm. Only if you do `return std::move(...)` does it use the move constructor. I'm not sure if this is mandated by the standard, or whether the compilers just aren't clever enough to handle this case, though.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the ternary was what caused issues. Expanding the `return flag ? t : f;` into `if (flag) return t; else return f;` made it use the move constructor instead. The reason for this is that the ternary expression results in `B&` instead.

Comment: @hyperair: The reason is not really that (`t` in `return t;` is also a `B&`), although you can use that as a reminder if that helps you. The real reason is that the compiler cannot *move out* of an *lvalue* in general, with a fixed set of exceptions in the standard, in particular in a return statement *when the exression is the **name** of a non-volatile automatic object* (12.8/31). The bold face is mine. In `return t;` the expression is the name, the copy can be elided and if it is not, the object must be moved. That's not the case in `return cond ? t : r;`

Answer (score 2):

Your code will never return by copy if `foo` has a working move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use an out-parameter instead of returning:

```
void f(foo& bar) { ... }
```

But in practice all compilers will do *NVRO*.